# Problems with using xdg-mime default. The default was successfully set but it is not used via xdg-open

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, xdg, dolphin-file-manager

Directories keep opening in Firefox when I use xdg-open. I do not want this.

I did:

`xdg-mime default dolphin.desktop application/x-directory`

and

`xdg-mime default dolphin.desktop inode/directory`

Yet, when I try

`xdg-open /local`

I still get a firefox window. Why is this? I even double checked with

`xdg-mime query default inode/directory`

and

`xdg-mime query default inode/directory`

and both of those commands result in

`dolphin.desktop`

I don't know if it would make a difference If I have used ssh to control the machine that I am referring to (I am not working on the machine that I am giving these commands, I have used ssh to control it via the terminal of my current machine).

The default program for directories on the machine I am sitting at is File Browser, not dolphin or Firefox, so it seems irrelevant.

Comment: You can try to debug by setting the `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL` env variable to a value greater than 1. If you are using bash: `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default inode/directory`. On my machine, `xdg-mime default` updated a different file what `xdg-mime query` was reading. Solved it by removing `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: @psmith Thank you! I've spent at least an hour trying to debug something similar. I had the same issue with different files on Fedora 22.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the change wouldn't work:

```
$ xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

Running with debugging on will show you the files queried:

```
$ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default application/pdf
Checking /usr/local/share//applications/defaults.list and /usr/local/share//applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/local/share//applications/defaults.list and /usr/local/share//applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/share//applications/defaults.list and /usr/share//applications/mimeinfo.cache
libreoffice-draw.desktop
```

Looking in that last file (where the match was found) gave me a hint:

```
$ grep application/pdf /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
application/pdf=libreoffice-draw.desktop;gimp.desktop;org.gnome.Evince.desktop;inkscape.desktop;
```

It's not called `evince.desktop` anymore, now it's `org.gnome.Evince.desktop`!

Once again, now using the new name:

```
$ xdg-mime default org.gnome.Evince.desktop application/pdf

$ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default application/pdf
Checking ~/.config/mimeapps.list
org.gnome.Evince.desktop
```

Much better!

Answer (score 1):

For me, further to running `xdg-mime default caja.desktop inode/directory`, it was running

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
```

which finally updated the default application.

After this, running `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` now showed the new default application.